# Dividing cubic spline computation

Tags: algorithm, math, curve-fitting, spline

I have `n` points (20k to 30k) in 3D, I want to interpolate them using cubic spline.  The problem here is that I will not have all of these points at the same time, they will be sent to me. so I don't want to wait until receive all of them to start the interpolation.

As a result, I choose to split these points into subsets, interpolate the first subset of points ,use it, and by the time start interpolate the next subset of points and so on

(split these points into subsets of hundreds points `n1,n2,...` and find the splines for each subset so that the result is identical to the result of the `n` point splines curves.)

I thought that overlapping these subset during computation is enough to do that but it seems not. what do you suggest to solve this?

Comment: How do you compute the coefficients ? The linear algorithm is so fast that parallelization could make it slower, except for zillion points.

Comment: I used tridiagonal matrix algorithm to find the second derivatives at points and then find the coefficients. 
I know it is linear and fast but I need to use the generated spline in short time. Waiting for thousands of points to be computed is too long in my case. so I choose to split these points, interpolate the first subset of points ,use it, and by the time start interpolate the next subset of points and so on.

Comment: Maybe choosing Parllelization term to explain my needs is not a good word. I changed the title of the question.

Comment: The discussion would be eased if you told us how many points you have. Even with an interpreted language, thousand points shouldn't be a big deal (below a millisecond).

Comment: 20k to 30k points in 3D, The problem here is that I will not have all of these points at the same time, they will be sent to me. so I don't want to wait until receive all of them to  start the interpolation

Comment: I update the question, it looks clear now.

Comment: Look at my update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the interpolation at any time, using the available points (presumably in the correct order !). Cubic spline interpolation is a very stable process and when you add more points, most of the curve remains unchanged.

If your concern is that you want to avoid redoing the whole computation several times, I guess that it is enough to work on several sections with some overlap (say 20 points) and discard the results of the 10 extreme points of all sections.

Comment: Thanks Yves, I will do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Calculation of interpolation splines is performed over the whole point sequence, and results for two separate halves with overlapping would be slightly different. Note, for example, that border condition for the last point of the first spline might include predefined bias or zero curvature, while the same part of the second spline is calculated to provide continuity.

You can try to calculate some kind of smooth transition for overlapping region.

**Edit**
After question update - I don't see relation between parallel treatment and your problem.

Instead you can connect subranges with C1-continuity:

Calculate splines interpolation for the first set of point. Use free-end condition - zero curvature. Remember bias (linear coefficient) in the terminal point.

For the every next set calculate spline interpolation using predefined starting bias - from the last set, and ending zero curvature condition again.

BTW, spline interpolation for thousands of points should work very fast (it is linear algorithm). Is it really bottleneck?

Comment: I used tridiagonal matrix algorithm ( linear algorithm) in spline computation but it is still bottleneck in my case.

Comment: I need C2 continuity between subsets.